# Alternatives to "ya me voy"

Tags: saludos

"Ya me voy" is sometimes heard often; for example at the end of the workday. What alternative phrases convey a similar meaning? "Me marcho" comes to mind, but it seems to connote walking in formation.

I realise this is an open-ended question that may or may not have a good, single answer. As such if this is a poor fit for this particular site I would agree with closing/deleting the question. In either case, thanks very much for your time and I look forward to any answers.

Comment: The verb "marchar", when not used in a reflexive way (i.e. "yo me marcho", "él se marchó" instead of "yo marcho", "él marchó") does not connote walking in formation ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. It is very interesting that there are different meanings for verbs when used in a reflexive and non-reflexive manner. I will definitely look further into this; again, thank you.

Comment: @Rorok_89 you mean "when used in a reflexive way does not connete walking in formation", don't you? Anyway, here in Spain there are places where "marchar" (without the reflexive" is used to mean "leave": "¿Ya marchas?" or "marcho, que llego tarde". In fact, [RAE says "marchar" means "irse"](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=marchar).

Comment: @MikMik right! I meant what you said. And yes to your second point. For instance in Galicia, where I live, it is generally said without the reflexive, because in Galician language it's said like that and it spread to Spanish, altough I think it's not entirely correct to say it that way in Spanish ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Me marcho» is perfectly fine and does not imply marching in formation. These are some other alternatives, albeit a bit colloquial: «Me largo», «Me piro».

Answer (score 3):

Alternativas más coloquiales:

- Me largo
- Me abro
- Me las piro (me las piro, vampiro)

Si vas a irte y tienes mucha prisa:

- Salgo pitando
- Me voy zumbando
- Me voy cagando leches (muy vulgar)
- Ya me he ido

Si vas a abandonar un grupo por cansancio, o desagrado ante alguna situación:

- Ahí os quedáis

Comment: No uses *Me abro* en México

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways comes to mind:

- Estoy por irme (I'm about to go)
- Voy saliendo (I'm walking out)
- Me estoy yendo (I'm leaving)

It depends on what country you are, which expression is used most commonly.

About the verb "Marchar", as MikMik said, it does not have the meaning of walking in formation when used in a reflexive way.